# Rails migration fails for`tsvector` with `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to run migrations on an existing Rails 7 app implementing search functionality in PostgreSQL.
Unfortunately, I'm having a problem with getting the migration to add the `tsvector` column.

Error when trying to run `bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace`:

```
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: ...earchable_index_col" tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvect...
```

Link to full console output: [Public gist](https://gist.github.com/malachaifrazier/e6e7dd601db78989060c1e45e779430d)

The full migration file:

```
class AddIndexForSearchableFieldsInDevelopers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      ALTER TABLE developers
        ADD COLUMN textsearchable_index_col tsvector
          GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvector('simple', coalesce(hero, '') || ' ' || coalesce(bio, ''))) STORED;
    SQL

    add_index :developers, :textsearchable_index_col, using: :gin, name: :textsearchable_index
  end

  def down
    remove_index :developers, name: :textsearchable_index
    remove_column :developers, :textsearchable_index_col
  end
end
```

```
Ruby: ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x86_64-darwin21]
PostgreSQL: psql (PostgreSQL) 14.3
Rails: Rails 7.0.2.4
MacBook: On MacOS Monterey MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020) 12.3.1
```

Comment: Are you trying to add a text searchable Identity column?

Comment: If you execute the alter table statement directly in PostgreSQL, it work?.  I think it's a database engine syntax error, and not Rails error.

Comment: @dbugger yup. That’s the plan

Comment: @JohanDonadoB. Trying that with `psql` now...

Comment: @JohanDonadoB. Yeah. Looks like a syntax error ```ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 3:           GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvector('simple', coalesc...```

Comment: That should work. Are you sure the server is PostgreSQL 14.3? What does `select version();` say from inside `psql`?

Comment: @muistooshort yooo! looks like my versions are goofed  ```psql (14.3, server 11.16)
Type "help" for help.

railsdevs_development=# select version();
                                                      version                                                      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.16 on x86_64-apple-darwin21.3.0, compiled by Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2), 64-bit
(1 row)```

Answer (score 2):

Found it!
The root cause was because that syntax isn't supported by my old PostgreSQL version (installed via `Homebrew`).

Upgrading like so fixed all the things:

Installed PostgreSQL via `Homebrew`?

Check your PostgreSQL version like so:

```
psql [username with correct permissions]
```

Then, check your version like so:

```
select version();
```

Your version should be at least 13.7. Here's mine:

```
 PostgreSQL 13.7 on x86_64-apple-darwin21.3.0, compiled by Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2), 64-bit
```

If your version is lower than 13.7, upgrade like so:

```
brew install postgresql@13
```